# How can I increase the efficiency of my Python implementation for the k Nearest Neighbours classification?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, nearest-neighbor, supervised-learning

I tried to implement the k Nearest Neighbour classification algorithm for images in Python, here is my code

```
    def classifyImage(self, RGBAValsForOneImage, kVal):
            redMaster = RGBAValsForOneImage[0]
            greenMaster = RGBAValsForOneImage[1]
            blueMaster = RGBAValsForOneImage[2]
            alphaMaster = RGBAValsForOneImage[3]
            L2DistanceDictionary = {}
            kLabels = []
```

for i in range(self.nImagesTrain):
            print(str("comparing to image nr " + str(i)))
            L2Norm = 0
            # label = self.LabelsTraining[i]

            for j in range(self.nPixel):
                redGreenBlueAlpha = self.RGBAPixelValuesTraining[i, j, :]
                redCompare = redGreenBlueAlpha[0]
                greenCompare = redGreenBlueAlpha[1]
                blueCompare = redGreenBlueAlpha[2]
                alphaCompare = redGreenBlueAlpha[3]
                L2Norm += np.sqrt((redCompare - redMaster) ** 2 + (greenCompare - greenMaster) ** 2 + (blueCompare - blueMaster) ** 2 + (alphaCompare - alphaMaster) ** 2)[0]
            L2Norm *= 100
            L2NormInt = int(L2Norm)

            alreadyThere = L2DistanceDictionary.get(L2NormInt, [])
            alreadyThere.append(i)
            L2DistanceDictionary[L2NormInt] = alreadyThere

        theSortedKeys = sorted(L2DistanceDictionary.keys())
        howManyUntilNow = 0

        for i in range(0, len(L2DistanceDictionary)):
            thekey = theSortedKeys[i]
            thevalue = L2DistanceDictionary[thekey]
            howMany = len(thevalue)
            for z in range(0, howMany):
                if howManyUntilNow < kVal:
                    kLabels.append(self.LabelsTraining[thevalue[z]])
                else:
                    break

        labels_to_count = (label for label in kLabels)
        c = Counter(labels_to_count)
        winLabel, count = c.most_common(1)[0]
        return winLabel

The basic idea of the classifyImage function is to compare the RGBA values of the pixels of the image which needs to be classified to the RGBA values of the other images in the training dataset and return the most common tag among the tags of the k nearest neighbours.

The problem with the code is that it is incredibly slow. Are there any ways to improve the efficiency? I almost never code in Python, so there might be easy ways to improve this code.

Comment: Attempts to improve efficiency should be made in concert with measurements. As it stands it's difficult to run this code. That also makes it inappropriate for [codereview.se]. See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you need a `sqrt`?

Comment: I can post more code, but running it would imply downloading an image dataset such as CIFAR-10 or MNIST. Should I edit the question with more code? My question is aiming mostly at common Python practices which I may be violating

Comment: Using `dict.setdefault` instead of `dict.get` will mean you don't need to reset the value of `L2NormInt` each time.

Comment: No, post less code, and a simple small amount of data. Reduce your example.

Comment: Also note, just because code takes a long time, doesn't mean it's slow.

Comment: `if howManyUntilNow < kVal:` is pointless as neither of the values changes in the loop.

Comment: You loops look-up indices. You should say `for key in sortedKeys:`, and `for value in thevalue:`

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I had overseen the mistake of not increasing the counting Variable, which is pretty bad. As for the sqrt() function, there is not really a need for it, it's just part of the L2 norm. I removed it now.